# Injecting dependencies into a class

Tags: angular, angular5

I created a class that needs a service:

```
export class RepositoryManager {
     //...
     private http: ApplicationHttpClient;

     constructor() {
         const injector = Injector.create({providers: [{provide: ApplicationHttpClient, deps: []}]});
         this.http = injector.get(ApplicationHttpClient);
     }
     //...
}
```

However, the `ApplicationHttpClient` service requires that the `HttpClient` be passed to the constructor.

```
@Injectable()
export class ApplicationHttpClient {
    //...
    public constructor(public http: HttpClient) { }
    //...
}
```

I tried to pass the `HttpClient` as deps (RepositoryManager):

```
     constructor() {
         const injector = Injector.create({providers: [{provide: ApplicationHttpClient, deps: [HttpClient]}]});
         this.http = injector.get(ApplicationHttpClient);
     }
```

However, the following error occurred:

> NullInjectorError: No provider for HttpClient!

**[EDIT]**

```
//...
imports: [
    HttpClientModule,
    //...
],
providers: [
{
  provide: ApplicationHttpClient,
  useFactory: ApplicationHttpClientCreator,
  deps: [HttpClient]
},
HttpClient,
//...
],
```

Comment: Dumb question: did you imported the HttpClientModule?

Comment: @EliasSoares Yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Who downvoted this answer? Can you elaborate what's wrong here?

First of all, you should import `HttpClientModule` in your root `AppModule`.

After that you have two options to create your custom injector:

```typescript
constructor(parentInjector: Injector) {
  const injector = Injector.create({
    providers: [{ provide: ApplicationHttpClient, deps: [HttpClient] }],
    parent: parentInjector
  });
  ...
}
```

or

```typescript
constructor(parentInjector: Injector) {
  const injector = Injector.create(
    [{ provide: ApplicationHttpClient, deps: [HttpClient] }],
    parentInjector
  );
  ...
}
```

Now DI system should be able to get `HttpClient` instance through passed parent injector.

**Tip:** if you doubt which parameters method takes always look at method signature

- https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/831592c3813593a09baf11f0a40840331ef605ce/packages/core/src/di/injector.ts#L81-L84

Comment: An error occurred when the class is instantiated `new RepositoryManager()`: Error: Expected 1 arguments, but got 0. What should be provided as a parameter? Is there a way to get the "parentInjector" without using the parameters?

Comment: Just add RepositoryManager  to providers array. You do not need to initialize it manually

Comment: I need to create multiple instances of the class `RepositoryManager` in the same component. Service provider is singleton, right?

Comment: If you add it to providers of component or directive it will have the same amount of instances as amount of components or directives

Comment: If you want to initialize it manually without parentInjector you have to initialize all dependencies yourself

Comment: I need to create multiple instances of the class `RepositoryManager` in the same script: `let foo = new RepositoryManager(); let bar = new RepositoryManager()`.

Comment: Where do you create it? Just pass root injector here

Comment: The instances of the class `RepositoryManager` are created in a service. 
How to pass the root injector?

Comment: Add `private injector: Injector` in constructor of your service and use it like `this.injector`